# How to run action on button click without rendering another page Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, action

Now I have a button(actually it is a table cell styled as a button) in my view. When user clicks on this button I want an action from the controller to run. However, this action should be completed on the same view, without redirecting to another page.

So, for now logic is like this: 
1) actionIndex works and render index view
2) On the index view there is a button on clicking which  we run the actionSend()
3) actionSend() works(sends email) but we do not redirect from the index view to somewhere else(just show success message)

View:

```
  <table style="width:100%; height:100%; color:white">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td><?= Html::a('Send to e-mail' ['result/sendPdf'])?>                                      
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Controller:

```
public function sendPdf(){
  $mailer = Yii::$app->mailer;
  $content  = Yii::$app->runAction('pdf/email');
  $message = $mailer->compose()
     ->setTo([$profileData->email])
     ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
     ->setSubject("Your pdf file is ready")
     ->attach($content, ['fileName' => 'Document.pdf', 'contentType' => 'application/pdf'])
     ->send(); 

}
```

Comment: wrap your button inside the `Pjax`

Comment: @Mirzhana Maxutova or make a JQuery function to render the `click` event on specific `button` and embed this code in view file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    $mailer = Yii::$app->mailer;
    $content  = Yii::$app->runAction('pdf/email');
    $message = $mailer->compose()
    ->setTo([$profileData->email])
    ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
    ->setSubject("Your pdf file is ready")
    ->attach($content, ['fileName' => 'Document.pdf', 'contentType' =>        'application/pdf'])
    ->send(); 
    }
```

AJAX code

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: your_url,
  success: function(result) {
      //code
  },
  error: function(result) {
     alert('error');
  }});});});
```